# Monitor connection pool of PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: apache-httpcomponents

I'd like to monitor the connection pool of a Apache httpComponents `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` but cannot find a way to access it.

We create our `HttpClient` using the following builder:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setMaxConnTotal(maxConnections)
            .setMaxConnPerRoute(maxConnectionsPerRoute)
            .build();
```

This creates an instance of an `InternalHttpClient`, which holds an instance of a `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`, which holds an instance of a `CPool`.

`CPool` would give us access to `T getRoutes()` and `PoolStats getStats(T)` — which looks promising to me. But I can't really find out how to get access to this `CPool`.

`HttpClient.getConnectionManager()` is deprecated. `InternalHttpClient.getConnectionManager()` is not deprecated, but returns a custom connection manager, which only exposes some of the methods of the real connection manager instance behind it.

So, how to get access to these stats? These would be very helpful for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ConnPoolControl` implemented by `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
ConnPoolControl<HttpRoute> connPoolControl = cm;
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(cm)
        .build();
```

Comment: Thank you! Did that and used `connPoolControl.getStats(route)` and `connPoolControl.getTotalStats()`. It's not what I originally intended to do, but I now think this is the best way.